# Empty Space Before doctype in Joomla Custom Template

Tags: php, joomla

I have custom joomla template: When I check the source code for this template I notice that there is a lot of empty lines before the `doctype` HTML tag.

[Demo Is here](http://beta.mtisambebi.ge/index.php)

**I try to make:**

Things that I have done:

1. I checked the CSS and the JavaScript files.
2. I checked the `index.php` file encoding (this is utf-8).
3. I removed the HTML and PHP codes step by step from the index.php file and when here is no code whatsoever the problem is solved.

I can not understand where is the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a plugin. Disable your non-core content and system plugins one by one until the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this issue, the problem was in moduletable.php file after end of php code there was empty space, so I delete it and problem is fixed.